# Как передают готовый проект из Eclipse другому человеку?

Tags: java, eclipse

Подскажите. Есть проект в Eclipse. Это небольшая программа, тестовое задание. Ее надо показать для проверки. Сказали что у меня должен быть готовый проект в Eclipse. Как это обычно делают? Как я понимаю просто файлы классов прислать не вариант. Я бы погуглил, но не знаю что гуглить даже. Спасибо.

Comment: export project eclipse типо такое гуглить?

Comment: github как вариант?

Comment: Можно просто всю папку с проектом отправить.

Comment: Я предлагал ссылку на гитхаб. Не подходит

Comment: А почему не подходит?

Comment: Как хотят так и передают. Конкретные требования нужно уточнять у принимающей стороны.

Comment: Я и уточнил. Вот ответ - Желательно иметь проект в Eclipse или Idea.

Comment: Так он уже в Eclipse, судя по вопросу. Что конкретно им нужно, знают только они. Универсального рецепта нет.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посмотрел в сторону использования maven или gradle, чтобы не было проблем с импортированием проекта в любую IDE(+ все сторонние зависимости сами подтянуться).
Ну и скидывать соотвественно папку с проектом просто, либо заливать на гитхаб, что конечно лучше

Comment: однозначно отдавать проект только с мавен/градлом.. ни одного проекта, что получал в особенности написанного в эклипсе так и не смог импортировать ни в Netbeans, ни в IDEA, даже самый маленький проект, в котором просто исходники и зависимости.. в итоге чтобы посмотреть как оно работает приходилось просто все самому создавать.. так что спасибо вам никто не скажет, если проект будет без поддержки сборщика проектов, а так поймут, что цените чужое время и хоть что-то понимаете..

Answer (score 0):

В общем сделал export `-general-archive fail`. Дал название архиву и получился `zip` моего проекта. Чтобы потом открыть нужно сделать `import-general-existing progect into workspace`